# Using printf awk function to output nth arguments

Tags: shell, awk

Given the following file's content:

```
alias command with whitespace-separated argument list
anotheralias othercommand and its arguments
```

how i can to print something like:

```
       alias = command with whitespace-separated argument list
anotheralias = othercommand and its arguments
```

Currently I'am using the below command, but it's wrong.

```
cat aliases | awk '{printf "%20s = %s\n", $1, $0}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat aliases | awk '{$1=sprintf("%20s =",$1);print}'
```

Comment: That leaves out the equals sign. Make the format string into `"%20s ="`, I think.

Comment: This works perfectly, though `cat` isn't necessary. A less clever version might be more transparent, though: `awk '{ name = $1; $1=""; printf "%20s =%s\n", name, $0 }' aliases`. No space after the `=` because there will be a leading space in `$0` after the now-empty `$1` field. Logically, this is no different than the answer given above; it just might help someone better understand why that answer works.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat aliases | awk '{ printf("%20s =", $1); $1=""; printf("%s\n", $0) }'
```

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```
sed 's/ /=/1' yourFile|awk -F= '{printf ("%20s = %s\n",$1,$2)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the shell:

```
while read line; do 
  set -- $line
  cmd=$1
  shift
  printf "%20s = %s\n" "$cmd" "$*"
done < filename
```